# Issue using Kendo Scheduler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-scheduler

I have been using Kendo controls for a while and their inclusion on HTML/Razor webpages is fairly simple: Here are some working examples:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProjectName.Models.MyModel>()
...

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
...

@(Html.Kendo().Button()
...
```

I want to start using the [Kendo Scheduler](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index) and in their example they have this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.Scheduler.TaskViewModel>()
```

So I tried this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<ProjectName.Models.MyModel>()
```

but it shows this error in the editor:

> *namespace ProjectName.Models.MyModel 
>
>
>   Error:
>
>       The type 'ProjectName.Models.MyModel' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetFactory.Scheduler()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ProjectName.Models.MyModel' to 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.ISchedulerEvent'*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Model that you are binding to the scheduler must inherit from *"ISchedulerEvent"* interface. This interface is present in "Kendo.Mvc.UI" namespace. e.g.

```
 // ViewModel required for managing appointments
public class SchedulerViewModel : ISchedulerEvent
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public string StartTimezone { get; set; }
    public string EndTimezone { get; set; }
    public string RecurrenceRule { get; set; }
    public string RecurrenceException { get; set; }
    //Add your own property here
}
```

Hope this will solve the error.

Comment: Do you have an example of a Model that inherits the `ISchedulerEvent` interface?

Comment: I have added an example of viewmodel that inherits from ISchedulerEvent in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! The Scheduler shows now, but there's no data in it... +1 for now. Can you help with binding the data to it?

Comment: Sure. Post codes that you have used for binding data to scheduler.
Else we can discuss in hangout "satyaranjan219@gmail.com".

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228036/unable-to-bind-data-to-kendo-scheduler) the specific question, I hope you can help!