# Unable to bind data to Kendo Scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I've got this Kendo Scheduler that is displayed in the View but without any data.

The Scheduler on the View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<ProjName.Models.ScheduleInspectionModel>()
    .Name("scheduler")
    .Views(views =>
    {
        views.DayView();
        views.WorkWeekView();
        views.WeekView();
        views.MonthView(mv => mv.Selected(true));
        views.AgendaView();
    })
    .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Read("ControllerName", "GetScheduleInspections")
    )
)
```

The datasource invokes the controller method below:

```
public ActionResult GetScheduleInspections([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    ScheduleInspectionModel sim = new ScheduleInspectionModel();
    var gsio = sim.getScheduleInspections();

    List<ScheduleInspectionModel> list = new List<ScheduleInspectionModel>();

    if (gsio.scheduleinspections != null)
    {
        foreach (wsScheduleInspection.scheduleInspectionOutput scheduleInspection in gsio.scheduleinspections)
        {
            ScheduleInspectionModel sim2 = new ScheduleInspectionModel
            {
                GlobalEquipConditionId = scheduleInspection.globalEquipmentCondition.id,
                Description = scheduleInspection.globalEquipmentCondition.code,
                Start = DateTime.Now,
                End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
                Title = scheduleInspection.globalEquipmentCondition.code,
                IsAllDay = true

            };

            list.Add(sim2);
        }
    }
    return Json(list.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

But this method is never run, despite being on the Scheduler Datasource property. It should run that method and return a list of inspections. I don't know why isn't the method being hit. With a Kendo Grid, for example, the method on the Datasource Read is hit as soon as the page is loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making sure your definition has these two items as I *think* they are required.

```
.Date(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13))
.StartTime(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13, 7, 00, 00))
```

**EDIT**

I was able to get the following code to work:

**Model**

```
// NOTE: It's important that your model class implements ISchedulerEvent
public class TaskViewModel : ISchedulerEvent
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public string StartTimezone { get; set; }
    public string EndTimezone { get; set; }
    public string RecurrenceRule { get; set; }
    public string RecurrenceException { get; set; }
}
```

**SchedulerController.cs**

```
public class SchedulerController : Controller
{
    // GET: Scheduler
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SchedulerViewModel();

        // In this case, it doesn't matter what this model is really since we're using AJAX binding
        return View(model);
    }

    // I usually have my binding methods for Kendo use HttpPost
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var data = new List<TaskViewModel>
            {
                new TaskViewModel
                    {
                        Start = new DateTime(2014, 12, 1, 8, 0, 0),
                        End = new DateTime(2014, 12, 1, 17, 0, 0),
                        Title = "Task 1"
                    }
            };

        return Json(data.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml (view)**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<TaskViewModel>()
    .Name("scheduler")
    .Views(views =>
    {
        views.DayView();
        views.WorkWeekView();
        views.WeekView();
        views.MonthView(mv => mv.Selected(true));
        views.AgendaView();
    })
    .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Read("GetData", "Scheduler")
    ))
```

If this doesn't work for you, I would make sure your versions (for Kendo, jQuery, etc) are correct.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that but nothing changed. And I don't think they are required... Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try marking the controller method with `[HttpPost]` maybe?  Or change your return to AllowGet

Comment: That's not it either, the method is still not called

Comment: Hmm, I will have to try some things at lunch or tonight as I don't use Kendo at my day job.

Comment: Hi! From where I can get the **ISchedulerEvent**?

Comment: 8 years later, this is still a problem from Progress - lack of adequate docs explaining why... like why would you have to do this ISchedulerEvent for the sake of implementing fields that are not even relevant to your own project, but only relevant to the Scheduler control and why forcing one to place it all in the Model?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Scheduler read is called as soon as it is loeded. But it may not be getting data in proper format as it expects. So it is not able to bind the data. If you can check for these modification:

1) Define the "Model" in "DataSource" of scheduler as defined in this [example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/scheduler/index).

2) Also the action method should return object of "MyModel" class(model on which scheduler is defined)
   not "ScheduleInspectionModel" class.